# Distinguish things like .app/.xcodeproj and actual folders in Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsfilemanager, finder

I am trying to build an alternative file manager that works similar to the default Finder in Cocoa.

As you can imagine, the app needs to show a list of files/subfolders in certain directory, and when the user click on an item, it checks whether it's a folder or a file that a user has clicked. If it's a folder, the app simply shows the content of the folder. If it's a file, it will be opened with the default application.

I used [`NSFileManager.file​Exists(at​Path:​is​Directory:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/filemanager/1410277-fileexists) to determine if an item at certain path is a folder. This works well in most cases, but for things like `something.app` or `project.xcodeproj`, they are also considered as directories according to the method.

I know it's true that technically they are just folders, but is there a way in Cocoa to distinguish them from actual folders?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use `(NS)URL`.
- Get the values for resource keys `isDirectoryKey` and `isPackageKey` via `resourceValues(forKeys`.

In case of bundles `isPackage` is `true`.